# Getting error {"detail":"Method \"GET\" not allowed."}

Tags: python-3.x, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am new to vue.js and django also,
Need some help on below issue.
I have created an api in which I am trying to fetch the data from one DB table and send the same to vue.js page to have check on it.

I am getting error "{"detail":"Method \"GET\" not allowed."}"

I tried it in multiple ways like sending the data in JSON form or as a array but still getting the same issuse

Model.py  below are the models for deserializing and for the table I am using to fetch the data

```
def deserialize_Issue(issue):
    """Deserialize user instance to JSON."""
    return {id': issue.id, 'IName': issue.IName, 'IDesc': issue.IDesc, 'ITeam': issue.ITeam,'IStat': issue.IStat, 'IChat': issue.IChat, 'Iuri': issue.Iuri, 'Ibridge': issue.Ibridge, 'Ibridgedetails': issue.Ibridgedetails  }

class Issue(TrackableDateModel):
    IName=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    IDesc=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    ITeam =models.CharField(max_length=500)
    IStat=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    IChat=models.CharField(max_length=2,default='NA')
    Iuri=models.URLField(default='NA')
    Ibridge=models.CharField(max_length=2,default='NA')
    Ibridgedetails=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='NA')

def __str__(self):
    return self.IName, self.IStat
```

IN my view.py file I have created the calls and the get method to fetch the data from the table.

```
class IssuesDetailsView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        DETAILS='Issue.objects.all()'
        serializer=deserialize_Issue(DETAILS,many=True)

        return Response ({'Issues': serializer.data})
```

abc.vue in vue.js file trying to acees the get the data

```
fetchIssueDetails () {
  $.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/chats/`, (data) => {
    this.Issues = data.Issues
  })

    .fail((response) => {
      alert(response.responseText)
    })
}
```

I want to read the table data in the vue.js file in for loop

Comment: Could also provide the contents of your `urls.py`?

Comment: Below is the url.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('chats/', views.ChatSessionView.as_view()),
    path('chats/<uri>/', views.ChatSessionView.as_view()),
    path('chats/<uri>/messages/', views.ChatSessionMessageView.as_view()),
]

Comment: I am using this URL befor to post the data also when I open a chat we page and using the same for get as well can it be because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the `urls.py` you've provided me in the comments:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('chats/', views.ChatSessionView.as_view()),
    path('chats/<uri>/', views.ChatSessionView.as_view()),
    path('chats/<uri>/messages/', views.ChatSessionMessageView.as_view()),
]
```

Notice how the url `/api/chats/` is tied to `views.ChatSessionView`, not `IssuesDetailsView`. Yet in your Javascript you are making the request to `/api/chats/`.

So one way to resolve your issue is

```
path('chats/', views.IssuesDetailsView.as_view()),
```

Comment: Hey Pavel, Thanks you so much for the quick resolution. I got this issue just one more questation if I have method say "{{startchat()}}" return in chat.vue and I have to call it from my page issue.vue on @click is it possible and how?
OR
can we call it from .py file?

Comment: @VishalDixit Sorry, I don't know how to answer this question. But you can create a new one on this website and someone else will come along.